# Как сделать подобный hover эффект

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу представить как реализовать подобное в своем макете. Пытался найти схожие эффекты на различных сайтах, но поиски не увенчались успехом, подскажите какое нибудь решение.

Comment: типа чтоб снизу появлялась картинка? это простейшая верстка

Comment: Подробнее, пожалуйста опишите задачу или ссылку например прикрепите. возможно это JavaScript, а не css

Comment: Могу предложить эквалайзер на css3 https://codepen.io/ordman/pen/WNeyEPJ

Answer (score 2):

Вот с [codepen](https://codepen.io/sotayamashita/pen/IproA)

```css
.equaliser {
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.bar {
 float: left;
 width: 7px;
 height: 10px;
 background: red;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}

.first {
 left: 7px;
 -webkit-animation: firstBar 1s infinite;
}

.second {
 left: 19px;
 -webkit-animation: secondBar 1s infinite;
}

.third {
 left: 31px;
 -webkit-animation: thirdBar 1s infinite;
}

.fourth {
 left: 43px;
 -webkit-animation: firstBar 1s infinite;
}

.fifth {
 left: 55px;
 -webkit-animation: secondBar 1s infinite;
}

.sixth {
 left: 67px;
 -webkit-animation: thirdBar 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes firstBar {
 0% {
  height: 10px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 30px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 10px;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes secondBar {
 0% {
  height: 30px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 10px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 30px;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes thirdBar {
 0% {
  height: 20px;
 }
 40% {
  height: 10px;
 }
 60% {
  height: 30px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 20px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="equaliser">
    <div class="bar first">
    </div>
    <div class="bar second">
    </div>
    <div class="bar third">
    </div>
    <div class="bar fourth">
    </div>
    <div class="bar fifth">
    </div>
    <div class="bar sixth">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде похоже:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item => {
  var t = '<div style="display:block;transform:rotate(180deg)">';
  for (var i=0; i<6; i++)
    t+= `<div class="band" style="left:${i*5}px;--h:${(5+i%3*5)}px"></div>`
  item.innerHTML += t+'</div>';
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.band {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.item:hover .band {
  height: var(--h);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Home</div>
<div class="item">About</div>
<div class="item">Goods</div>
```

Comment: Уже разобрался :) .Но возник второй вопрос откуда эти цифры `${i*5}` и вот эти `--h:${(5+i%3*5)}` и как вы узнали что именно  эти операции сделают похоже на то что в картинке ?Сори если вопрос глупый просто не понимаю откуда вы всегда берете математические решение

Comment: @Demon__ANT ${} это часть синтаксиса шаблонов строк, выраженте внутри скобок вычисляется и добавдяется в это место в строке, `5+i%3*5` так вычисляется максимальная высота блока, i%3 это остаток от деления номера итерации на 3 - получается последовательность 012012, —h это css переменная